# NodeJS - how to use latest version v11.10.0?

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

How to have additional - latest NodeJS version (v11.10.0) ?

Tried with NVM but it says that can not find that version..

Comment: Do you just need the latest version installed or two Node versions installed at the same time?

Comment: 2 nodes at the same time..

Comment: What does `nvm ls-remote` output?

Comment: `dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/awk
  Reason: image not found`

Comment: Seems to be a Mac thing. Did you install nvm using Homebrew? If so, brew uninstall it, and install it using the instructions here: https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install--update-script